# Need Help Debugging Unexpected EOF Javascript error

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, wordpress

I'm running Woocommerce on Wordpress. I get `SyntaxError: Unexpected EOF` in Safari
when trying to reveal new fields when I click on a "Add new Field" button. And in Firebug I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal


var newRow = '\
```

This is the script that this error is associated with, and I don't know how to fix it.

```
<script>

                            jQuery(document).ready(function(){

                                 var newRow = '\

                                     <tr>\

                                        <td align="center">\

                                            <select name="wc_custom_checkout_newfield[enabled][]">\


                                                    <option value="1">Yes</option>\


                                                    <option value="0">No</option>\


                                            </select>\

                                        </td>\

                                        <td>\

                                            <select name="wc_custom_checkout_newfield[section][]">\


                                                    <option value="billing">Billing</option>\


                                                    <option value="shipping">Shipping</option>\


                                                    <option value="account">Account</option>\


                                                    <option value="order">Order</option>\


                                            </select>\

                                        </td>\

                                        <td>\

                                            <select name="wc_custom_checkout_newfield[type][]">\


                                                    <option value="text">Text</option>\


                                                    <option value="textarea">Textarea</option>\


                                                    <option value="password">Password</option>\


                                                    <option value="date">Date</option>\


                                                    <option value="country">Country</option>\


                                                    <option value="state">State</option>\


                                                    <option value="select">Select</option>\


                                                    <option value="checkbox">Checkbox</option>\


                                            </select>\

                                        </td>\

                                        <td><input name="wc_custom_checkout_newfield[label][]" type="text" value="New Field Label" /></td>\

                                        <td>\

                                            <input name="wc_custom_checkout_newfield[field_name][]" type="hidden" value="newfield" />\

                                            <input name="wc_custom_checkout_newfield[field_name][]" type="text" value="newfield" disabled="disabled" />\

                                        </td>\

                                        <td><input name="wc_custom_checkout_newfield[placeholder][]" type="text" value="New Field" /></td>\

                                        <td><input name="wc_custom_checkout_newfield[class][]" type="text" value="form-row-wide" size="12" /></td>\

                                        <td><input name="wc_custom_checkout_newfield[options][]" type="text" value="" size="12" /></td>\

                                        <td><input name="wc_custom_checkout_newfield[order][]" type="text" value="" size="6" /></td>\

                                        <td align="center">\

                                            <select name="wc_custom_checkout_newfield[required][]">\


                                                    <option value="1">Yes</option>\


                                                    <option value="0">No</option>\


                                            </select>\

                                        </td>\

                                        <td align="center">\

                                            <input name="wc_custom_checkout_newfield[default][]" type="hidden" value="0" />\

                                            <input id="removeRow" type="button" value="X" title="remove this row">\

                                        </td>\

                                    </tr>';



                                 jQuery('#addRow').click(function(){

                                  jQuery('#block').append(newRow);

                                  reIndex();

                                 })



                                 jQuery('#removeRow').live('click', function(){

                                  jQuery(this).closest('tr').remove();

                                  reIndex();

                                 })



                                 function reIndex(){

                                   jQuery('#block').find('.index').each(function(i){

                                   jQuery(this).html(i+2);

                                  })

                                 }



                                })

                                </script>
```

I tried disabling plugins, and removing all other javascript to see if there is a conflict, but nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of all those double line breaks.

The backslash characters at the end of each line in the quoted string (`var newRow = '...';`) are [line continuation markers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/805113/1679849). These signal to the Javascript parser that the following line is a continuation of the current line. In effect, a backslash followed by a line break character will both be ignored.

But because you have somehow turned every line break into two line breaks (probably by saving the file with Windows `\r\n` line breaks), you are destroying the continuity so that Javascript is unable to parse the string.

So for example:

```
// This is fine:
var string1 = 'This string is split \
across two lines';

// ... but this is not:
var string2 = 'This string is split \

across three lines';
```